# Can I use OPTION (MAXDOP 1) for a query within an IF statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, if-statement, hint

I want to preface this with the fact that I do understand that using `OPTION (MAXDOP)` is generally frowned upon and undesirable. However, just saying "don't use `OPTION (MAXDOP)`" does not address the narrow focus of the question at hand. For purposes of this question, say I have a scenario where I am backed into a corner, and this is something I'm stuck with due to other issues that are beyond what I actually want to ask for this specific question. Let's not get stuck on those reasons for the time being please. Specifically for this question, I am writing a stored procedure wherein I have an IF statement something like:

```
IF ((SELECT TOP 1 Identifier 
     FROM SomeTable 
     WHERE <some conditions>) IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN 
    <do some stuff>
END
```

I would like the query within the IF statement to run with `OPTION (MAXDOP 1)` - again, I know this is generally not what you'd want to do, let's save that discussion for the sake of this question. Can I do this? It seems like whether I put the `OPTION (MAXDOP 1)` bit at the end of the line with the IF, immediately after IS NOT NULL, or after `<some conditions>`, my query editor is telling me it's not allowed there. Is there somewhere I can put it to make this occur?

Comment: "...this is something I'm stuck with due to other issues that are beyond what I actually want to ask for this specific question. Let's not get stuck on those reasons for the time being please." - given that sounds like an XY problem, why not start with the actual problem ?

Comment: See if this work for you `IF ((SELECT TOP 1 Identifier FROM SomeTable OPTION (MAXDOP 1)  WHERE ) IS NOT NULL) BEGIN END`

Comment: Same syntax exception :/

Comment: Hi. Can you include the actual error message in your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting. It seems like you cannot use query hints on a query enclosed in parenthesis that is not a derived table - that is, one that expects a single value. Actually, I do not know how this clause is called to search for it through the documentation, so more enlightening answers are welcome.

Still, you can use a variable to do what you want:

```
SELECT TOP 1 @identifier=Identifier 
FROM SomeTable 
WHERE <some conditions>
option (maxdop 1)

IF @identifier IS NOT NULL......
```

Comment: Thank you! I had tried:

SET @Identifier = (SELECT TOP 1 Identifier FROM SomeTable WHERE <some conditions>)

But had run into the same issues with including OPTION (MAXDOP 1) as in the IF statement. Forgot I could inline setting the variable!